# Unauthorized error 401.0 for Asp.net mvc site with IIS anonymous authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I'm facing Unauthorized error 401.0 for Asp.net mvc remote site with IIS anonymous authentication.

Details are provided in the github link - https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/501

Please let us know fix if anyone face the similar issue.

I have tried to set anonymous authentication as true and disabled remaining authentications in IIS.

I'm expecting site should be accessed from IIS and launch AAD authorization code flow.

Note: Same code is working fine in local using IIS Express from visual studio.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps to solve this issue:

First, changing the Anonymous User identity from Specific user (IUSR) to Application Pool Identity.

And then right-click the web application in the left pane, select *Edit Permissions* -> select the *Security tab* -> click *Edit* -> *Add* and add IIS `APPPOOL\NameOfAppPool`. Make sure the Application Pool Identity has read and execute permissions of the folder.

**Failed Request Trace Log:**

```
186. NOTIFY_MODULE_START                ModuleName="ASPxHttpHandlerModule", Notification="PRE_EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotification="false" 
187. NOTIFY_MODULE_END                  ModuleName="ASPxHttpHandlerModule", Notification="PRE_EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"
188. NOTIFY_MODULE_START                ModuleName="__DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_bf3231ec-59ca-4437-ab87-64fb44d10615", Notification="PRE_EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotification="false"
189. NOTIFY_MODULE_END                  ModuleName="__DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_bf3231ec-59ca-4437-ab87-64fb44d10615", Notification="PRE_EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 
190. NOTIFY_MODULE_START                ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotification="false"
191. GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER        HeaderName="X-AspNetMvc-Version", HeaderValue="5.2", Replace="false" 
192. GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER        HeaderName="Cache-Control", HeaderValue="private", Replace="true" 
193. GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER        HeaderName="X-AspNet-Version", HeaderValue="4.0.30319", Replace="true"
194. MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS   ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="401",               HttpReason="Unauthorized", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.(0x0)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""
195. NOTIFY_MODULE_END                  ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false",  NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 
196. NOTIFY_MODULE_START                ModuleName="ASPxHttpHandlerModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotification="true" 
197. NOTIFY_MODULE_END                  ModuleName="ASPxHttpHandlerModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotificationEvent="true", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"
198. NOTIFY_MODULE_START                ModuleName="Session", Notification="RELEASE_REQUEST_STATE", fIsPostNotification="false"
```

Comment: hi @samwu, Thanks for looking. I have followed the above steps but still getting 401.0 unauthorized error. do you think , any changes to be done on application pool?

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see details about 401.0 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: hi @samwu, i have tried with failed request tracing and it seems issue with Owin startup is not recognized in IIS.  Also, i have include below app settings for owin startup issues but doesn't help.                                    
  `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="AssemblyName.Startup, AssemblyName" />
        <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />  `

Comment: Can you post the details of the frt log?

Comment: hi @samwu - here is failed request trace logs [Failed Trace Logs](https://github.com/sivakumar715/myrepo/blob/main/iis_failed_trace_logs.txt) . please look into this and let me know if you aware of this issue.

Comment: The link you provided is invalid, please post the full log content.

Comment: hi @samwu - here is the complete log.  [IIS Trace Logs](https://github.com/sivakumar715/MyTestShare/blob/main/iis-failed-error-logs-latest)

Note: Same owin integration code is working fine in Local both IIS express & IIS Manager. It's not working
only in windows server 2012, IIS 8.5.

Comment: You need to check the folder permissions on your server and check that the account that you are using to run your application has access to that folder.